# render_to_string from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I want to use a Rake task to cache my sitemap so that requests for `sitemap.xml` won't take forever. Here's what I have so far:

```
  @posts = Post.all

  sitemap = render_to_string :template => 'sitemap/sitemap', :locals => {:posts => @posts}, :layout => false
  Rails.cache.write('sitemap', sitemap)
```

But when I try to run this, I get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `headers' for #<Object:0x100177298>
```

How can I render a template to a string from within Rake?

Comment: this article is helpfull
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725119/render-a-view-from-a-rake-task

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

```
  av = ActionView::Base.new(Rails::Configuration.new.view_path)
  av.class_eval do
    include ApplicationHelper
  end

  include ActionController::UrlWriter
  default_url_options[:host] = 'mysite.com'

  posts = Post.all

  sitemap = av.render 'sitemap/sitemap', :posts => posts
  Rails.cache.write('sitemap', sitemap)
```

Note that I converted my template to a partial to make this work

Comment: where are you use default_url_options hash?

Answer (score 4):

There is a [post](http://starterstep.wordpress.com/2009/05/23/rendering-views-in-rake-tasks/) about how to be able to access ActionView::Base methods and context from rake task.

However, this is a monkeypatch. Why not use the rails' [cache mechanism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) to accomplish caching? :)

Later edit:
The **render_to_string** function is defined in ActionController::Base context.

Below is a solution on how to make it work from rake tasks, taken from [omninerd](http://www.omninerd.com/articles/render_to_string_in_Rails_Models_or_Rake_Tasks).

```
# In a rake task:
av = ActionView::Base.new(Rails::Configuration.new.view_path)
Rails.cache.write(
  "cache_var", 
  av.render(
    :partial => "view_folder/some_partial", 
    :locals => {:a_var => @some_var}
  )
)
```

Comment: The cache mechanism is great, but sometimes you really just want to periodically generate the content offline into a file. A rake task is the perfect place for that - good link.

Comment: I can't use caching because I can't render the sitemap even once in response to an HTTP request since it takes more than 30 seconds and Heroku times out HTTP requests at 30 seconds

Comment: You have a point. So, does the approach from the pasted link work for you?

Comment: This actually doesn't work -- I get the error "undefined method 
'render_to_string' for #<ActionView::Base:0x101db8808>" (note that I am using `render_to_string :template => whatever` and the post author is doing `render :partial => whatever`). I'd convert my template to a partial, but it's a `.builder`, which I don't think works as a partial? Any ideas?

Comment: Actually this *does* work when I make the `.builder` a partial. Now I'm getting a new error when I try to call `x_url` (e.g., `post_url`). How do I get access to the URL-generating helpers?

Comment: +Horace Loeb : Did you resolve the access to the URL-generating Helpers?

Answer (score 1):

Recently I wanted to take a rake task defined like Horace Loeb mentioned and translate it into a self contained background job, but it didn't easily translate.

Here is my implementation for Rails 2.3.x because the [Rails 3 implementation](http://jguimont.com/post/5582583230/how-to-render-a-full-page-template-in-a-rake-task-with) I found wouldn't work.

```
# Public: Template to render views outside the context of a controller.
#
# Useful for rendering views in rake tasks or background jobs when a
# controller is unavailable.
#
# Examples
#
#   template = OfflineTemplate.new(:users)
#   template.render("users/index", :layout => false, :locals => { :users => users })
#
#   template = OfflineTemplate.new(ProjectsHelper, PermissionsHelper)
#   template.render("projects/recent", :projects => recent_projects)
#
class OfflineTemplate
  include ActionController::UrlWriter
  include ActionController::Helpers::ClassMethods

  # Public: Returns the ActionView::Base internal view.
  attr_reader :view

  # Public: Convenience method  to
  delegate :render, :to => :view

  # Public: Initialize an offline template for the current Rails environment.
  #
  # helpers - The Rails helpers to include (listed as symbols or modules).
  def initialize(*helpers)
    helper(helpers + [ApplicationHelper])
    @view = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.view_path, {}, self)
    @view.class.send(:include, master_helper_module)
  end

  private

  # Internal: Required to use ActionConroller::Helpers.
  #
  # Returns a Module to collect helper methods.
  def master_helper_module
    @master_helper_module ||= Module.new
  end
end
```

This is available as a gist: https://gist.github.com/1386052.

Then you can use the class above to create an OfflineTemplate to render your views in a rake task:

```
task :recent_projects => :environment do 
  template = OfflineTemplate.new(ProjectsHelper, PermissionsHelper)
  puts template.render("projects/recent", :projects => recent_projects)
end
```