# How to turn my rails app into static content?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails app fetches a bunch of xml feeds once a day, loads them into the db and then displays them in aggregate. I'm thinking that I can save on server memory if I just output the pages as static files and let them be served directly by the front-end server (nginx in my case). I asked in an IRC room and was told to not use rails and create the files using rake tasks. However, I'm wondering what the easiest way would be to go about doing this. Layout, asset files and content are in different places in rails obviously, so I guess I would need to combine the layout and content and then insert the css/javascript.

Any thoughts/ideas are welcome.

[Solved]

I ended up using the examples from [render_to_string from a rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619823/render-to-string-from-a-rake-task) and made some tweaks to get the following code inside my rake task:

```
views_path = Rails.root.to_s + "/app/views"
av = ActionView::Base.new(views_path)
av.class_eval do
  include ApplicationHelper
end

products = Product.all
a = av.render(:template => "products/show", :layout => "layouts/application", :locals => { :@products => products } )
```

This then renders both the template and the layout, and allows the use of the @products instance variable inside the template just as you would if you were using a controller.

Then I just need to write the output of the render to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a task like this you can use [Rails' built in caching mechanisms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html).

There is [another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619823/render-to-string-from-a-rake-task) which shows some example code of how to build code to write that cache manually from something like a rake task.

Comment: Thanks for the links. It looks like this would work well, but still testing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) or [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) could be used?

I've only used middleman, but you could use a rake task and support script to get the latest xml feeds and stick that into middlemans data dir (i.e. `data/feeds.yml`), then use your existing layouts to render that yaml file. Middleman and rails share a lot of similar tech for rendering etc.

You'd have to modify your layouts a little bit.

You could probably find gems to replace yaml with something else if you wanted.